# How can I create bookmarks for temporary logging and FIXME markers in Xcode 6 for both Objective-C and Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, navigation, xcode6

I would like to be able to add temporary logging statements and FIXME markers to my Objective-C and Swift code that I can find quickly with bookmarks.   I would prefer not to use breakpoints as they can not be labeled and would clutter up the Breakpoint navigator as I am debugging.

The solution should provide me with a means to find and navigate to these statements and markers that may be located in several files.

The use of #pragma mark (Objective-C) and // MARK: , // FIXME: , // TODO: (Objective-C, Swift) to add entries to the method jump bar is not what I'm looking for, as it clutters that list and is useful for only one file at a time.

Placeholders using //<# Text #> can be used for navigation, but they don't provide an overall list and have the same issue as the pragma mark method of being useful for only the current file being edited.

Comment: You mean aside from [`// FIXME: ` & `// TODO: `](http://nshipster.com/swift-documentation/)?

Comment: Hi @mattt - I've used those as well, but they have the same drawback as // MARK: They can clutter the method jump bar list and if I wanted to find them in many different files I would need to perform a text search.  I just updated the question to mention this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using the Issue Navigator.   I wrote a blog article discussing this in depth at:

http://finalize.com/2014/10/20/logging-and-bookmarks-with-objective-c-and-swift/

The following are the key pieces from the article.

[image: Objective-C and Swift Screenshot]

**Objective-C temporary logging and FIXME markers**

Add the following to a common header file:

```
#define DO_PRAGMA(x) _Pragma (#x)

#define FIXME(x) DO_PRAGMA(message (STR(__LINE__) " FIXME: " #x))

#define CLOG(x) NSLog(@#x); DO_PRAGMA(message (STR(__LINE__) " NSLog: " #x))

// If ENABLE_PRAGMA_FOR_FLOG is set, FLOG and NLOG both use pragma. 
// If not set, only NLOG uses pragma.
#if ENABLE_PRAGMA_FOR_FLOG
#define FLOG(LogType, MacroType, FormatLiteral, ...)  NSLog (@"%s(%u): " LogType " \n" FormatLiteral "\n\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);  DO_PRAGMA(message (STR(__LINE__) " " MacroType ": " FormatLiteral " " #__VA_ARGS__))

#define NLOG(FormatLiteral, ...)  FLOG("","NSLog", FormatLiteral, ##__VA_ARGS__)

#else

#define FLOG(LogType, MacroType, FormatLiteral, ...)  NSLog (@"%s(%u): " LogType " \n" FormatLiteral "\n\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);  

#define NLOG(FormatLiteral, ...)  FLOG("","NSLog", FormatLiteral, ##__VA_ARGS__) DO_PRAGMA(message (STR(__LINE__) " NSLog : " FormatLiteral " " #__VA_ARGS__))
#endif
```

The above code takes advantage of Diagnostics Pragmas (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) and a variadic macro (macro taking a variable number of args)

You can use the macros as in the following examples:

```
FIXME(Need to fix this bug in the next iteration)

CLOG(A simple constant string log message)

NSString *msg = @"My message";
NLOG("msg = %@",msg)
```

Note that the FIXME and CLOG macro instances require no quotes.  The NLOG macro requires no @ string prefix, but does use quotes.  None of the macros require a trailing semicolon.

**Objective-C permanent logging**

If you want to use a macro for permanent logging without showing up in the Issue Navigator, you can create a project specific macro such as the following.  Note how we leave off the DO_PRAGMA() after the FLOG() call:

```
#define PLOG_CORE_DATA(FormatLiteral, ...)  FLOG("PLOG_CORE_DATA","PLOG_CORE_DATA", FormatLiteral, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

This will provide the power of NLOG to add function and line number to your log output, along with the ability to enable the macro to show up in the Issue Navigator if you wish (see next section).

**More on FLOG**

To show all logging macros in the Issue Navigator (i.e. NLOG and project specific versions), set ENABLE_PRAGMA_FOR_FLOG prior to any of the header code above:

```
#define ENABLE_PRAGMA_FOR_FLOG 1
```

You will note that FLOG takes 2 arguments named LogType and MacroType.  The first allows a project specific macro to add a prefix to the console output.  The second is used when ENABLE_PRAGMA_FOR_FLOG is set to 1 to allow a project specific macro to specify a label for the Issue Navigator.

**Swift temporary logging and FIXME markers**

Swift does not use a preprocessor, so pragma flags and macros are not an option.

It is still possible though to provide similar functionality to the NLOG and FIXME macros used with Objective-C by making use of the benign warning "Treating a forced downcast as optional will never produce 'nil'"

I've created some code to do this available under the MIT license at:
https://github.com/scottcarter/SNLog

Here is an example of the usage from the documentation for SNLog:

```
// Add a FIXME marker to Issue Navigator
g_fixme = g_anyFixme as SNLog.Fixme

// Log to console and add to Issue Navigator
g_log = SNLog.info("<message>") as SNLog

// Only log to console, but still add function and line number to output.
SNLog.info("<message>")
```

There are more usage cases shown on the SNLog GitHub page.

Details on why the warning is generated and how SNLog works is discussed in the blog article http://finalize.com/2014/10/20/logging-and-bookmarks-with-objective-c-and-swift/